# php - How to increase variable by 100

Tags: php

I am querying a URL (via php command line) that returns 100 values at a time only. So instead of me doing the increment (by 100) manually, how would I go about increasing it automatically?

The URL for example is: `example.com/getdata.php?start=0&return=100`

```
for ( $start = 0; $start < 300001; $start++ )
{
    print ( "$start value is ".$start ) ;
    $start = $start+100;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put increment into for loop

```
for ( $start = 0; $start < 300001; $start=$start + 100 )
{
    print ( "$start value is ".$start ) ;

}
```

Comment: If you want you can replace `100` with `$return`

Answer (score 2):

your current code is increasing loop counter by once as you are using $start++ in your for loop If you replace it with $start+=100, then it will increase counter by 100. such as

```
for ( $start = 0; $start < 300001; $start+=100 )
{
    print ( "start value is ".$start ) ;

}
```